# How to establish Multi Domain Google SSO between NodeJS app and WordPress

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, authentication, single-sign-on

I have Google SSO implemented in ReactJS/ExpressJS App and I want to make the user when logs in this Node App to be registered as well in the WordPress website

I have here in this section the data that comes from React to ExpressJS and that works fine, so I want to when the user register/login to be directed to another WP website and find him self registered there also, I added another rule in route.post but it doesn't work

`routesGoogle.post("/login", googleLogin, secondGoogle);`

```
export async function googleLogin(req, res) {
    try {
        const { body } = req;

        // await verifyGoogle();
        // After successfully creating tshe user, send the data to Zapier
        const zapierResponse = await axios.post('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/39045/3annwb9/', {
            name: body.user.name,
            email: body.user.email,
            date: new Date().toISOString() // Current date in ISO format
        });

        // Check if the Zapier webhook call was successful
        if (zapierResponse.status !== 200) {
            console.error('Failed to send data to Zapier', zapierResponse.data);
        }

        const { user: googleUser } = body;

        let user = await userModel.findOne({ email: googleUser.email });

        if (!user) {
            user = await createUser(googleUser);
        }

        const token = await createToken(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET, '7d');

        res.redirect("https://XXXXXXX.shop"); // I added this but doesn't work 
        return res.json({ token });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" }); // Improved error message
    }
}
```

WordPress

```
// In your WordPress plugin or theme's functions.php

// Add an endpoint to handle token-based authentication
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('custom-plugin', '/authenticate', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'authenticate_user',
  ));
});

// Callback function for handling authentication
function authenticate_user($request) {
  $data = $request->get_json_params();

  // Implement your WordPress authentication logic here
  // Check if the provided token is valid

  if ($token_is_valid) {
    return rest_ensure_response(array('message' => 'Authentication successful'));
  } else {
    return rest_ensure_response(array('error' => 'Invalid token'), 401);
  }
}
```